# Google Firebase Dynamic Link: Add custom parameter to dynamic link

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I have the following code to open dynamic link(supposing `https://example.page.link` is a dynamic link):

```
let url = URL(string: "https://example.page.link?param=abc")!
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The preview page is displayed(with the open button) but the parameter `param=abc` is lost/ignored.
Is it possible to add custom parameter to dynamic link and why the parameter is ignored here.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem that you have and the solution is simple.

**https://example.page.link**

This link that you provided is the short version and you can't send parameter in this link but in the large version that you see in the FireBase console:

**https://example.page.link/?link=https://example.com.br/?PARAMETER=VALUE&apn=com.example.br**